# Permanently set drop to FALSE for vector operators in R

Tags: r, matrix

As stated in R [documentation](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Extract.html), the operator '[' is defined in this way:

```
x[i, j, ... , drop = TRUE]
```

Is there a way to redefine it in order to set `drop` parameter default value to `FALSE`?

Comment: You can change `[.data.frame` easily. However, I don't think it can be done for `matrix` or `array` objects without performance and other problems.

Comment: And how do you change `[.data.frame`?

Comment: `[` <- function(...) base::`[`(...,drop=FALSE)

Comment: Or, something like `\`[.data.frame\` <- function(..., drop = FALSE) base::\`[.data.frame\`(..., drop = drop)` I guess (with the backticks, as included).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
`[` <- function(...) base::`[`(...,drop=FALSE)
```

This should prevent some undesirable behaviour in R where a matrix that is reduced to one row or one column will suddenly behave like a `c(number,number,number)` instead of `matrix(c(number,number,number),ncol=1)`

Comment: If I define this, extracting the first element of a numeric vector of length 10 gets slower by a factor of ~ 50.

Comment: ... but it's just an overhead of a few microseconds. The chance you are writing an algorithm that calls `[` millions of times for it to even matter is small.

Comment: I'm hoping the OP intends to use this only for his own functions and not to expect that all subsetting done internal to compiled library functions will follow suit!   Personally,  I'd be very tempted to suggest writing one's functions out and then using a text editor to globally replace "[^]]" with ",drop=FALSE]"  :-)  (regexp)

Comment: You can probably write an alternative class for matrix objects where you provide your own subset operator implementation. Also probably should have written it as `[` <- function(..,drop=FALSE) base::`[`(...,drop=drop) where here you can set drop whenever you want to.

Comment: @flodel Normally I would agree, but vector subsetting is one of the most basic language features and it's quite often used within loops.